# Get latency of packet(TCP\UDP)

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, udp

I have some server, which have to respond differently, depending on latency of packet.

Is it possible to get latency("time of travelling") of separate packet right on server side?(using Python preferably(but not neccessary) or somehow configured server)?

Example for clear understanding:

```
# Pseudo-code
def handle_packet(packet):
    if packet.latency > X:
        # Declare war on the latency gods
    else:
        # Make peace with the latency gods
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I'm understanding your question correct you're going to have to modify the client to have a "ping" operation. The server will have to ping the client, and the client will then immediately respond with a pong and the server will have to time how long it took from sending the ping to getting the pong. This would be best done with UDP or TCP out-of-band because with normal TCP your packet may get stuck in the queue behind other data that's still being transmitted artificially increasing your ping.

To answer more the question I think you're asking. Getting the round trip time from computer a to computer b and back to a is not a standard operation in TCP or UDP, it's handled by ICMP (ping). You're free to implement your own ping operation with TCP or UDP, it just doesn't come standard.

P.S. Before you ask, there's a few reasons not to use an ICMP ping. One, there's a slight chance it may be firewalled. Two, it won't work in general from a non-privileged process. Most OSes don't support the ICMP protocol and therefore you have to get raw access to the network interface which is a privileged operation.

**Response to your comment:**

It appears what you're asking for is to get the time it took a packet to go from the client to the server without doing a ping-pong. The only possible way to do this would be if the clocks were synchronized and you put the time on the client into the packet. A. There's a good chance your client is not going to have a synchronized clock. B. Even if the client does have a synchronized clock you're going to have to change the protocol at the application level to add this timestamp in, which it sounds like you're not allowed to do by your problem statement.

Comment: Yeah, but i have to get latency right on server, for separate packet, without sending response! Thats the main feature(and problem).

Comment: @progerz Edited based on what I guess you're asking then

Comment: I am not going to downvote but recommending UDP or really any "out-of-band" timing mechanism has some problems. The more glaring one is that it's quite possible the main TCP flow and the out-of-band measurement will go on separate paths. Or will be handled differently by the intervening switching elements. It is inherently difficult to say anything about a specific flow using "out-of-flow" mechanisms.

Comment: @cnicutar Ok, it's difficult to determine what progerz wants, but it's the only way to get up to date information. You have a good point about them taking different paths, but I don't believe your solution (tcpi_rtt from the tcp_info struct) is going to have a nice up to date value in it. Also, he specified TCP/UDP so I just picked one and ran with it. He specifies that he wants this in python, so I'm sort of assuming he doesn't want to have to write his own C extension module (or w/e like cffi) to get access to the necessary data.

Comment: @CrazyCasta sorry if it was unclear. 
I could write some C extension for that goal, it is not very complicated

Comment: @progerz Ah, well you tagged python in your question, that's the only reason. Are you running on linux (we're just going to assume it's at least linux 2.4 if you are).

Comment: @CrazyCasta server running on linux, client on windows.

Comment: **for edited message** Yep, looks like its only solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. It is well known in distributed systems that you cannot trust to have the same clock on all nodes. Only if you have a mechanism like NTP you could have similar clocks but still there is clock drift (it depends on the error you can live with). Even if you had the same clock, you also need a way to determine when the packet left the PC and you don't have that. Is it a controlled environment or you could have unknown clients? Can you tolerate any margin of error in the measurements? Are we talking about times of 100 ms or less than 10 ms? These are the keys to solve your problem.

Adding info to my response as per @progerz comment
If NTP and clock drift of a few ms works for you then you may have a mechanism to do what you need. Just remember the less controlled the environment you have, the less useful this can be. For example, this could work well within the same datacenter and not that well between a client connected in a restaurant with Wifi and a server in a datacenter.

Regarding the modification of UDP ot TCP, if you need to modify UDP header basically you are implementing a new protocol, that's a possibility and you'll need to assign a new protocol number to it. You won't be able to use datagram AF_INET sockets (or stream socekts in case of TCP), you have to consider working with lower level sockets like raw socket (or packet sockets but this shouldn't be necessary).

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
raw_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, your_new_protocol_number);
```

The alternative is to create an application layer protocol over UDP or TCP. In that case you are going to be able to use datagram/stream sockets.

Comment: Now i`m trying to make that scheme to work just for me, and its really interesting.  As i read, NTP allows to have similar clocks, with difference up-to few ms.
So i need to somehow modify UDP packet, to insert timestamp...

Comment: @progerz I modified my response to add info after reading your comment

Comment: @progerz, here is another link explaining how NTP is used for Cassandra: https://blog.logentries.com/2014/03/synchronizing-clocks-in-a-cassandra-cluster-pt-1-the-problem/ . Tell me if this response was useful.

Comment: thank you @rodolk ! Yep, i'll tell you later(just don`t have time for that).
If you want to help me, i can fully describe my idea(there is only small part of that), and you answer, whether its possible or just waste of time =)

Answer (score 0):

In case the accuracy of the measure is not important, you may guess this value from some application behavior. For example, with TCP you can assume that the client is sending a request right after doing "connect", and that the processing time on the client is negligible relative to the network time.
Maybe you can find other places in the application, where the client is expected to send you something after certain response from the server - then again you can use the time diff to estimate the RTT.

Of cause, if higher accuracy is needed, these methods will not work very well.